# Duda sobre liberías ICU y compilación estática

Tags: c++, qt, compilar

Tengo un programa compilado contra las librerías de Qt compiladas estáticamente.
El programa no funciona en otros ordenadores cuando tienen diferentes versiones de las librerías `libicuuc`, `libicudata` y `libicui18n`. Siempre hablando de ordenadores bajo linux.

Lo cierto es que si hago `ldd` al programa me da, entre otros, esto:

> libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60
> (0x00007faa2d726000)
>
> libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60
> (0x00007faa2d36e000)
>
> libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60
> (0x00007faa28401000)

Buscando cómo construir de nuevo las librerías de Qt integrando las librerías de [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/), veo que [hay una opción](https://icu.unicode.org/) para de forma expresa NO integrarlas, que es añadir la opción `-no-icu`  en el `./configure`, lo cual me induce a pensar que si no he añadido esa opción, como fue el caso cuando compilé en su momento, estas librerías deberían de haber estado integradas, y no es el caso.

¿Alguien me puede arrojar algo de luz sobre esto? Gracias!

Comment: Nunca compilé las librerías Qt para utilizarlas en linux, siempre en win  (en linux vi otras... gtk o wxWidget) pero si lo que quieres es eso de incluirlas de formas estática y tal supongo que tendrás que recompilar, las librerias... y la aplicación.... me extrañaría otra solución. Porque como dices el programa no funcionará en otro pc.